# TypeError when running Mercurial on AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, syntax, mercurial

When I run "ported" Mercurial on GAE (from http://bitbucket.org/durin42/mercurial-appengine/), I meet:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 511, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/yt-source/1.346021588701137656/hgappengine/multi_hgapps.py", line 45, in get
    return self.run()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/yt-source/1.346021588701137656/hgappengine/multi_hgapps.py", line 68, in run
    code = self.dispatch(repo_name)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/yt-source/1.346021588701137656/hgappengine/multi_hgapps.py", line 91, in dispatch
    app.get()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/yt-source/1.346021588701137656/hgappengine/hgapp_mod.py", line 160, in get
    return self.run()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/yt-source/1.346021588701137656/hgappengine/hgapp_mod.py", line 250, in run
    content = getattr(webcommands, cmd)(self, req, tmpl)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/yt-source/1.346021588701137656/mercurial/hgweb/webcommands.py", line 245, in shortlog
    return changelog(web, req, tmpl, shortlog = True)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/yt-source/1.346021588701137656/mercurial/hgweb/webcommands.py", line 224, in changelog
    lessvars['revcount'] = revcount / 2
TypeError: 'function' object does not support item assignment
```

I'm newly in Python GAE...

Comment: Have you contacted the author of this code?

Comment: Yes, but he doesn't reply... Maybe he is busy or my email go to his spam box...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problems: We need to use Mercurial 1.6.4 or older... Newest version (1.7) is not supported by appengine-mercurial